# If I install Windows 7 in one partition, will it erase other data partition I have?

Tags: windows-7, boot-partition

I have my OS on one partition and my data on another, on the same drive.

1. If I install Windows 7 on the OS partition, will it erase the data partition? I'm guessing not, but this isn't something I want to risk.
2. Also, how would it treat/what should I do about the XP install currently occupying it?
3. How much OS partition space will Win7 suck down? The partition is 100 GB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No, it will not erase the data partition, but it's always good practice to backup your data before doing anything.
2. Windows 7 will replace XP totally.
3. A clean Windows 7 installation takes up [slightly less than 5GB](http://www.compdigitec.com/labs/2009/03/17/windows-7-clean-install-size/).

Comment: Marked as answer. :)